# Require.js timeout with Charles proxy

Tags: javascript, requirejs, charles-proxy

Code works absolutely fine but when Charles proxy running in background, I get following error in Chrome and Firefox. Charles proxy is running at default settings.

***Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: jQuery,handlebars
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout require.js:8 

F require.js:8 

C require.js:13 

(anonymous function)***

```
OS: OS X 10.8.4
Charles: v 3.7 
Chrome : 28.0.1500.71
Firefox : 22.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to hosts file. Requirejs was throwing timeout because localhost was taking too long to resolve. Everything works fine after updating hosts file to this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain  
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 username.lmuk.local
255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1              localhost 
fe80::1%lo0      localhost
```

More information available [**here**](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/).